# Обработка сообщения боту в зависимости от выбранной команды и текста сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Написал вот такой простенький метод:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['author'])
def author(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ты хочешь узнать, кто создал этого бота?")

    if message.text == "Да":
        bot.reply_to(message, "а вот йух тебе")
    elif message.text == "Нет":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Не хочешь — как хочешь.")
    else: 
        bot.reply_to(message, "Ответь только 'да' или 'нет'.\nБез кавычек.")
```

И когда я пишу команду /author, бот реагирует следующим образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему, и как исправить?
Спасибо.

Comment: `Почему?` 1) вы получили команду 2) написали на нее сообщение в тот чат 3) сразу же проверили текст команды `1)` и написали еще сообщение. Как исправить я не знаю, т.к. с этим api не работал. Как вариант, отслеживать последнюю выбранную команду и написанные боту сообщения и в обработчике сообщения смотреть какая была последняя команда и что в текущем сообщении пришло. Возможно, можно и проще сделать такую машину состояний

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш `handle`r обрабатывает команду `/author`. Внутри этого же обработчика отрабатывает и ваш `if`. В данном случае ваш `message.text` будет иметь значение `/author`. Потому он и попадает в последнюю секцию `else`. Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать, вам нужен еще один обработчик, который будет обрабатывать простой ввод текстовых сообщений и уже туда вставить свой `if`. Еще бы конечно запоминать предыдущую команду, чтобы каждый раз на ответ да или нет не возвращать результат `if`'a.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, вот только как подобное реализовать-то на деле?